# Java sort via bucket value

Tags: java

Am trying to sort via a certain value in the function,

```
 Collection users = roster.getEntries();
 if(!users.isEmpty()) {

 Iterator userIterator = users.iterator();
 while(userIterator.hasNext()) {
      String name = user.getName()==null?user.getUser():user.getName();
```

Now before iterating, I want to sort this Collection by the user's name. Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You should rather use the for each loop instead of this iterator clutter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Collections.sort() and provide a Comparator, provided the collection preserves order. If it doesn't copy it into an ArrayList.

Unless you are using Java 1.4 or older I would use generics and the for-each loop.

```
Collection<User> users = roster.getEntries();
if(!users.isEmpty()) {
    Collections.sort(users, SORT_BY_NAME_COMPARATOR);
    for(User user: users) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, am very new to Java, could you guide me to the right documentation for the same?

Comment: @Alec http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29

Comment: If you want to find something I use http://www.google.com/search?q=Collections+sort

Answer (score 1):

Consider you have a User class. That class could implement [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). Read about this interface and the usage.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply try it by applying anonymous `Comparator` class

```
Collections.sort( users , new Comparator() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        return ( (User)o1 ).getName().compareTo( ( (User)o2 ).getName() );
    }
});
```

Comment: If I try this as is, it says "no suitable method found for sort"

Comment: make sure you have included `import java.util.Collections;`

Comment: Yes, I've done that but it does not work. I think I'll have to get a Java Expert to help me.